# Pig - how to select only some values from the list (not just simple distinct)?

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig

Let's say I have intput_file.txt (user_id, event_code, event_date):

```
1,a,1
1,b,2
2,a,3
2,b,4
2,b,5
2,b,6
2,c,7
2,b,8
```

as you can see, user_id = 2, has events like this: `abbbcb`
I'd like to have a result like this:

```
1,{(a,1),(b,2)}
2,{(a,2),(b,6),(c,7),(b,8)}
```

So when we have few events, with the same code, I'd like to take only the last one.

Can you please share any hints?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you are describing is what `GROUP BY` does.

In this case:

```
B = GROUP A BY user_id;
```

Gets your records together by `user_id`. Your data will now look like this:

```
1,{(a,1),(b,2)}
2,{(a,2),(b,6),(c,7),(b,8)}
```

You say you only want the last one (I assume you mean the one with the greatest `event_date`). To do this, you can do a nested `FOREACH` with an `ORDER BY` to sort by date, and then take the first one with `LIMIT`. Note that this has arbitrary behavior when there are ties.

```
C = FOREACH B {                          
   DA = ORDER A BY event_date DESC;                
   DB = LIMIT DA 1;                         
   GENERATE FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN(DB.event_code), FLATTEN(DB.event_date);
}
```

Your data should now look like this:

```
1,b,2
2,b,8
```

---

Another option would be to use a UDF to write some custom behavior on the groups given by `GROUP BY`:

```
B = GROUP A BY user_id;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE YourUDFThatYouBuilt(group, A);
```

In that UDF you'd write whatever custom behavior you want (in this case return the tuple with the greatest date)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use the [DistinctBy](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/DistinctBy.html) UDF from [Apache DataFu](http://datafu.org) to achieve this.  This UDF, given a bag, returns the first instance found for a given field.  In your case the field you care about is event_code.  But we have to reverse the order, as you actually want the last instance.

One clarification though.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the intended output is:

```
1,{(a,1),(b,2)}
2,{(a,3),(b,6),(c,7),(b,8)}
```

That is, the (a,3) event occurs for member 2.  The (a,2) event occurs for member 1.

Here's how you can do it:

```
-- pass in 1 because we want distinct by event code (position 1)
define DistinctBy datafu.pig.bags.DistinctBy('1');

FOREACH (GROUP A BY user_id) {
  -- reverse so we can take the last event code occurrence
  A_reversed = ORDER A BY event_date DESC;

  -- use DistinctBy to get the first tuple having an occurrence of a field value
  A_distinct_by_code = DistinctBy(A_reversed);

  -- put back in order again
  A_ordered = ORDER A_distinct_by_code BY event_date ASC;

  GENERATE group as user_id, A_ordered.(event_code,event_date);
}
```